# Gorm is only preloading first result in slice

Tags: go, go-gorm

Been using `gorm` and it's fantastic, the only problem is with the nested `preloading` it only seems to populate the first result, this is my code:

```
// Shoutbox msg is the db struct
type ShoutboxMsg struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID  int `sql:"index"`
    User    User
    Message string
}

// User is the User table in the database
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username     string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    Email        string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    PasswordHash string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    UserLevel    int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    Characters   []Characters
    MainPosts    []ForumMainThreadsPosts
    ReplyPosts   []ForumMainPostsReplies
}

// Characters is a table in the database
type Characters struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID             int    `sql:"index"`
    CharacterName      string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    CharacterServer    string `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterLevel     int    `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterMain      bool   `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterClass     string `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterPic       string `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterSpec      string `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterCSSClass  string `sql:"not null"`
    CharacterTalentImg string `sql:"not null"`
}
```

then I load it like:

```
msgs := []ShoutboxMsg{}
db.Preload("User").Preload("User.Characters").Find(&msgs)
```

But it only populates the first:

`msgs[0].User.Characters`

-

`msgs[1].User.Characters`  and up all don't have characters but if I do:

```
for i, msg := range msgs {
    characters := []Characters{}
    db.Model(msg.User).Related(&characters)
    *(&msgs[i].User.Characters) = characters
}
```

This seems to work fine but does `Preload` not populate beyond the first result?

Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/658